# LexicalComposer 'destroy' is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lexicaljs

I have an app that imports a private NPM package that contains a text editor component that is powered by `LexicalComposer`. Currently in my app, I am trying to upgrade to version 18 of React and I am running into the following error `'TypeError: destroy is not a function'` when my implemented Lexical editor component attempts to unmount. I have mainly been using the console to determine that the error may be coming from Lexical's implementation of `LexcialComposer`

With React 18, I know that this error usually implies there is an incorrect usage of asynchronous actions within `useEffect()` react hooks. I am wondering if Lexical support React 18? and if it does, where would that error be coming from? and how to fix it.

The following is the implementation of the Lexical text editor that leverages `LexicalComposer`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { LexicalComposer } from '@lexical/react/LexicalComposer';
import { RichTextPlugin } from '@lexical/react/LexicalRichTextPlugin';
import { ContentEditable } from '@lexical/react/LexicalContentEditable';
import LexicalErrorBoundary from '@lexical/react/LexicalErrorBoundary';
import { StandardPlugins } from '@myapp/myapp-lexical-react';
import styles from './myappLexicalEditor.module.scss';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';
import { myappLexicalEditorTheme } from './myappLexicalEditorTheme';
import { MyappLexicalEditorProps } from './myappLexicalEditor.types';

const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

/**
 * My App implementation of the Lexical Rich Text Editor
 */
const LexicalEditor = ({
    editorConfig,
    children,
    toolbars,
    readOnly,
    onEditorChange,
    editorClass,
    editorStyle,
    editorContainerClass,
    editorContainerStyle,
    editorChildren,
    toolbarClass,
    placeholder,
    plugins,
    disableHistoryPlugin,
}: MyappLexicalEditorProps) => {
    const Placeholder = placeholder || null;
    return (
        <LexicalComposer initialConfig={{ ...editorConfig, theme: { ...myappLexicalEditorTheme, ...editorConfig.theme }, editable: !readOnly }}>
            <div className={toolbarClass}>
                <>
                    {Array.isArray(toolbars) &&
                        toolbars.map((toolbar, i) => {
                            const { ToolbarComponent, props, showToolbar } = toolbar;
                            const finalShowToolbar = showToolbar !== undefined ? showToolbar : !readOnly;
                            return finalShowToolbar ? <ToolbarComponent key={i} {...props} /> : '';
                        })
                    }
                </>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <divstyle={editorStyle} >
                        <RichTextPlugin
                            contentEditable={<ContentEditable />}
                            ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
                            placeholder={!readOnly ? Placeholder : null}
                        />
                        {editorChildren}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <StandardPlugins onChange={onEditorChange} disableHistory={Boolean(disableHistoryPlugin)}/>
            <>
                {plugins && plugins.map((pluginObj, i) => {
                    const { PluginComponent, props } = pluginObj;
                    return <PluginComponent key={i} {...props} />;
                })}
            </>
            {children}
        </LexicalComposer>
    );
};

export default LexicalEditor;
```

Below is the error I am seeing and where I think the error is being traced back from.

```
Uncaught TypeError: destroy is not a function
    at safelyCallDestroy (react-dom.development.js:22928:5)
    at commitHookEffectListUnmount (react-dom.development.js:23096:11)
    at commitPassiveUnmountInsideDeletedTreeOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:25094:11)
    at commitPassiveUnmountEffectsInsideOfDeletedTree_begin (react-dom.development.js:25044:5)
    at commitPassiveUnmountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24952:11)
    at commitPassiveUnmountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24937:3)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27034:3)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26980:14)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26931:5)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26678:5)


The above error occurred in the <observerComponent> component:

    at observerComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/mobx-react-lite/es/observer.js:51:73)
    at div
    at observerComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/mobx-react-lite/es/observer.js:51:73)
    at _class (webpack-internal:///./frontend/js/stores/index.js:163:88)
    at I18nextWithTranslation (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/withTranslation.js:28:31)
    at div
    at LexicalComposer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@lexical/react/LexicalComposer.dev.js:43:3)
    at w (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@myapp/myapp-lexical-react/lib/components/MyappLexicalEditor/MyappLexicalEditor.es.js:29:172)
    at div
    at div
    at Summary (webpack-internal:///./frontend/js/components/reusableComponents/Deal/ResponseDetails/components/SummarySection/Summary/summary.js:41:25)
    at div
    at SummarySection (webpack-internal:///./frontend/js/components/reusableComponents/Deal/ResponseDetails/components/SummarySection/summarySection.js:23:32)
    at div
    at observerComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/mobx-react-lite/es/observer.js:51:73)
    at _class (webpack-internal:///./frontend/js/stores/index.js:163:88)
    at I18nextWithTranslation (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/withTranslation.js:28:31)
    at div
    at TabPane (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rc-tabs/es/TabPanelList/TabPane.js:16:24)
    at div
    at div
    at TabPanelList (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rc-tabs/es/TabPanelList/index.js:16:17)
    at div
    at Tabs (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rc-tabs/es/Tabs.js:73:17)
    at Tabs (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/antd/es/tabs/index.js:45:17)
    at div
    at observerComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/mobx-react-lite/es/observer.js:51:73)
    at I18nextWithTranslation (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/withTranslation.js:28:31)
    at _class (webpack-internal:///./frontend/js/stores/index.js:163:88)
    at I18nextWithTranslation (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/withTranslation.js:28:31)
    at Route (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-router/esm/react-router.js:648:29)
    at Switch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-router/esm/react-router.js:850:29)
    at div
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@myapp/myapp-ui/components/container/Container.js:18:22)
    at observerComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/mobx-react-lite/es/observer.js:51:73)
    at _class (webpack-internal:///./frontend/js/stores/index.js:163:88)
    at I18nextWithTranslation (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/withTranslation.js:28:31)
```

I have tried wrapping the Component in an error boundary in an attempt to at least see more information about the error. I had no luck there.

I also tried attaching a `useRef` ref to the main implementation in my bigger app and using a `useEffect()` callback to assign it to `null` when it unmounts.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the issue was rooted in my application all along. Although with the upgrade to React 18 I went through and updated all `useEffect(async () => {...code})` to now be async wrapped functions inside. It turns out there were other places I found that were not async `useEffect()` functions, but had asynchronous actions inside. Those needed to be wrapped in async fucntions, then called inside the `useEffect()`